# Incorrect key detected when doing JOIN in Vapor's Fluent

Tags: mysql, swift, join, vapor

I've already set up the Models correctly (using Sourcery) but when I try to perform a JOIN, Fluent can't detect the key correctly.

Simplified model:

- Client: id / company_id
- Company: id
- FK: Company.id ~ Client.company_id

Not working:

```
let query = try Client.makeQuery()
            .join(Company.self)
```

> [MySQL Error: Unknown column '**company.client_id**' in 'on clause'] [Identifier: MySQL.MySQLError.1054 (badFieldError)]]

Working:

```
let query = try Client.makeQuery()
            .join(kind: .outer, Company.self, baseKey: Client.Keys.companyId, joinedKey: Company.Keys.id)
```

Why does vapor think the key is **company.client_id** ?

Edit. Using Vapor 2.4.4